# data member access in template programming

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming

I am creating a template class with specialized behavior for two different sizes, and general behavior in general class as below::

```
template<typename T, size_t DIM>
class Dataset
{
public:
    // all the constructors are defaulted
    // all the general behavior implementation

    std::vector<T> _data;
};
```

Given the flow of data for the class below, I am expecting to have access to _data vector, right ?!

```
template<typename T>
class Dataset<T, 1>
{
public:
    T & operator()(const size_t & index)
    {
        return _data[index];
    }
};
```

however, I get the compilation error of _data couldn't be resolved. What is the problem here ?!! Thanks

Comment: Don't use identifier beginning with underscore. Change to something like `data_`.

Comment: @cshu That's not a problem. The rules are IIRC a `_Capital` or a `__something` aren't allowed. But I write it your way just so I don't have to think about it

Comment: @Justin Quoting section 2.10/3: `Each identifier that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in the global namespace.`

Comment: @cshu "in the global namespace"

Comment: @Justin I still think most people would like to avoid naming that could cause confusion. When I see any identifier beginning with underscore I assume it belongs to implementation. Besides, you could be shadowing another identifier and there is no warning.

Comment: @cshu Which is why I do it your way, but some people prefer the prefixed underscore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A class template specialization is its very own class, unrelated to the primary template.  So `Dataset<T, 1>` does not have a `_data` member because you did not declare one in its class definition.

If you need common features among different specializations of the same template, you can move them to a shared base class.